# How to get Redirect URL of Curl

Tags: php, regex, curl, web-scraping, preg-replace

I want to scrap a webpage info using curl. Here is my script -

```
$data[0] = "WP8558753";
$url = "http://www.searspartsdirect.com/part/search.html?q=".$data[0];
$ch = curl_init();  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "http://parts.sears.com/partsdirect/part-model/'".$data[0]."'?shdMod=".$data[0]); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

$output = curl_exec ($ch); 

echo curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);

curl_close ($ch);
```

I want to fetch this url `http://www.searspartsdirect.com/part-number/WP8558753/0026/110.html?pathTaken=partSearch&q=WP8558753` in variable.

How can I do this.. please provide some guidance.

Comment: That particular URL (`http://www.searspartsdirect.com/part/search.html?q=WP8558753`) doesn't actually return a redirect. It returns a 200 and a full page of HTML. (Presumably, it later loads a new URL via JavaScript.) Just `curl`ing the page here won't help you.

Comment: what I can do then? Can u please provide any suggestion

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the curl option to follow redirects

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```